# Should my rep be combined?

Tags: support, reputation

I was just wondering if the reputation from both my Super User and Stack Overflow accounts should be combined?

On one of them I have 600~ and on the other I have 100.

Are they supposed to be separate?

Comment: Duplicate over at MSO: [Why not merge reputation across SO, SF, and SU?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6336/why-not-merge-reputation-across-so-sf-and-su).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, they're separate. That's by design.

Answer (score 14):

What Hyppy said is true but just to elaborate further... Just because you are a programming wiz does not mean you are also a Database/cooking/English/Gaming Expert. You have to prove your worth on each of the sites and show that you deserve to have additional privileges. On a related note- if are member of a Stack Exchange site with over 200 rep and you link your account with another stack exchange site they do give you a 100 rep bonus. At least you can then comment, upvote, and do other basic functions on the site.

Comment: that makes good sense, thanks Kyle.

Comment: Does that bonus occur if you joined both sites below 100 and then progressed on one and not the other?

Comment: I joined several of the sites, got my rep past 200 on a few of them and then joined another of the sites and then I got the 100 point bonus on all sites. SO the trigger is linking an account to another but it affects all your linked accounts.